# Can i remove the OR from this regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
((.*?)(\(.*?\))|(.*?))
```

I would like to remove the | as i think there is a better way of matching this. Here are some example strings that I would like it to match

```
myString

myString(1234)
```

if it has brackets I want to capture the contents of the brackets as a separate capture group. It never has to capture both types of string.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What have _brackets_ have to do with this? (Note: brackets are: `[]`)

Comment: @Shahbaz parenthesis are also brackets you know... certainly if you speak to a linguist http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: I would commonly refer to [] () {} as brackets, but might concede that {} are braces!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `(...)` part is optional, you can make the sub-regex which matches it optional as well:

```
((.*?)(\(.*?\))?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
.*?(\(.*?\))?
```

This makes the bracketed part optional, and the first `.*?` will match everything if the bracketed part isn't there.